# 大文字でない環境変数を利用することに問題はありますか

Tags: linux, unix

例えば、以下を実行するとわかる通り、環境変数は必ずしも大文字でなくても動作します。

```
$ hello=fuga sh -c 'echo $hello'
fuga
```

#### 質問

大文字でない環境変数を利用することに、慣習に従っていない以上の技術的な問題はありますか？

Comment: タグでlinux, unixとありますし、例えば将来Windows環境に移植することがあるかも、と言ったことは考えないと言うことですよね?

Comment: @OOPer はい。考えません。厳密に定義するのならば、 posix 互換環境と考えていただければと思います。

Comment: 英語版Stack Overflowで似た質問を発見しました。 [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) こちらでは慣習（convention）だとされているようです。

Comment: http_proxy あたりは小文字のほうがふつうになってる気がします。

Answer (score 15, accepted):

問題ないです。

#### 仕様

仕様的には、

> The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.
>   —— [Environment Variable Definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

とあり、小文字の環境変数はアプリケーション用に予約されているとのことなので、むしろ標準ツールが使用する環境変数との衝突を避けるという意味で使用が推奨されているとも読めます。

#### 慣習

慣習的には、他のアプリケーションやユーザーに設定させて引き継ぐことを意図する環境変数には大文字を使い、それ以外には小文字を使うことが多いようです。書籍『UNIXプログラミング環境』には、

> 特別な意味をもつ変数は伝統的に大文字で綴るので、ユーザーの作る変数名は通常、小文字で書く。

とあり、小文字の変数を `export` して子プロセスに渡す例も出てきます。